# Find the $m$ which is this function is continuous(2 variable functions)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

Find the range of the positive real number $m$ such that $f$ is continuous

### $f(x,y) =\begin{cases}
{x^my+xy^m \over x^{12}+y^{20} } & \text{$(x,y) \neq (0,0)$} \\
0 & \text{$(x,y) =(0,0)$}
\end{cases}$

---

My attempt)

### $\Vert f(x,y) \Vert = \Vert {x^my \over x^{12}+y^{20}} \Vert + \Vert {xy^m \over x^{12}+y^{20}} \Vert$

### $\le \Vert {x^{12} \over x^{12} +y^{20}} \Vert \Vert x \Vert ^{m-12}\Vert y \Vert + \Vert {y^{20} \over x^{12} +y^{20}} \Vert \Vert x \Vert \Vert y \Vert ^{m-20} $

### $\le  \Vert x \Vert ^{m-12}\Vert y \Vert + \Vert x \Vert\Vert y \Vert^{m-20} $

Since $\Vert f(x,y) \Vert \to 0$  as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$,therefore $m \geq 20$

But the answer was $m \geq 19$. I don't know why answer should be like that.

Any answer, different method and advice always welcome.

p.s.) Are there any trick or simple method for checking the continuity in 2 variables function?

Comment: Is it possible to use polar coordinates and make sure that it converges to zero independent of the angle? Hence to have the radius which goes to zero in the numerator?

Comment: Though I used polar coordinate, I couldn't find any way to conclude the value "$19 \leq m$"

Comment: Hmm if you use polar coordinates and reason that $1/(x^{12}+y^{20})\leq 1/y^{20}$ you should get $r^{m+1}/r^{20}$ gives you $m+1 > 20$.

Comment: @Tamim, Yes I agree your thought, But this method doesn't implied the $m = 19$ I.e. we only ensure continuity of the $f$ when the $m>19$  but doesn't show any information continuity of the $f$ when the $m\leq19$(Or my workbook answer is incorrect...)